# Comparing group of items over few data frames - by rows

Tags: r

I have couple of data frames which I would like to compare. Let's start with showing two examples of data:

Data1:

```
> dput(data1)
structure(list(cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
14, 15, 15), description = c("BTB", "BTB", "CVA", "BAS", "TRK", 
"EXT", "LRA", "CAW", "CAW", "CAW", "CAW", "CAW", "TTE", "TTE", 
"MYU", "MTQ", "PLI", "KQA", "STG", "STG", "ATF", "ATF", "REW", 
"REW", "REW", "KIR", "KIR", "ROR", "ROR", "FRQ", "QEQ", "QEQ"
)), .Names = c("cluster", "description"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", 
"Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
"Volvo 142E", "Volvo 144", "Chrysler", "Ford 131", "Ford 144"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Data2:

```
    > dput(data2)
structure(list(cluster = c(3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 13, 11, 14, 15, 15, 
1, 1, 2, 2), description = c("TRK", "EXT", "LRA", "CAW", "CAW", 
"CAW", "CAW", "CAW", "TTE", "TTE", "MYU", "MTQ", "PLI", "KQA", 
"STG", "STG", "ATF", "ATF", "REW", "REW", "REW", "KIR", "KIR", 
"ROR", "ROR", "FRQ", "QEQ", "QEQ", "BTB", "BTB", "CVA", "BAS"
)), .Names = c("cluster", "description"), row.names = c("Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", 
"Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
"Volvo 142E", "Volvo 144", "Chrysler", "Ford 131", "Ford 144", 
"Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive"), class = "data.frame")
```

So in both data sets we can find the same row.names and description but in different order. 
I would like to do the comparison between the cars found in the same cluster. So, let's take for example `"Merc 240D"`:

It belongs to `cluster ==6` together with (`data`):

```
            cluster description
Merc 240D         6         CAW
Merc 230          6         CAW
Merc 280          6         CAW
Merc 280C         6         CAW
Merc 450SE        6         CAW
Merc 450SL        6         TTE
Merc 450SLC       6         TTE
```

Let's now move to the second `data2`. This time `"Merc 240D"` belongs to cluster 5 together with:

```
Duster 360                5         LRA
Merc 240D                 5         CAW
Merc 230                  5         CAW
```

This time there are just three cars in the same cluster but only one which can be found together with `"Merc 240D"` in both data sets is `"Merc 230"`.

I would like to perform such analysis for every row (car) in my data set. Analyze to which cluster it belongs, together with who and compare to other data sets.

The problem is that I've got like 20 data sets to compare like that. I believe loop is necessary!

As an output I would like to have the table like that (just example):

```
               nr_partners  name of partners       Description Descr_partners 
Merc 240D         3         Merc1, Merc2, Merc3       CAW       CAW, TTE, TTE
```

Is something like that possible to do ? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Do you want the number of partners and the name of partners that are in same clusters over all your 20 datasets?

Comment: At the begining I can use the smaller amount of data sets.

Comment: Do all the tables have all the car models ?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to return your example output table for each table. You can use `aggregate` and `merge`. Hereafter how to do it for the model names, you can adapt for the other informations:

```
    # first make a column aggregating all the partners for each cluster
    pasteAlphabetical <- function(vectNames){
        return(paste(sort(vectNames),collapse=","))
    }
    byCluster <-aggregate(row.names(data1),by=list(cluster=data1$cluster),pasteAlphabetical)

    # then you can attribute this to each row
    data1 <- merge(data1,byCluster,by="cluster")
```

But if you want to see which models are in the same clusters in a number of tables, you'll need to use `merge` on the clusters over all your tables and then aggregate the models that are always in the same cluster:

```
    # get the clusters in each table for each car
    SummarizeClusters <- function(datas){
        for(id in 1:length(datas)) datas[[id]]$names <- row.names(datas[[id]])
        summaryDat <- datas[[1]][,c("cluster","description"),drop=FALSE]
        summaryDat$names <- row.names(datas[[1]])

        for(iData in 2:length(datas)){
            summaryDat <- merge(summaryDat,datas[[iData]],by="names",all=TRUE)
        }

        return(summaryDat)
    }
    datas <- list(data1,data2)
    sumDat <- SummarizeClusters(datas)

    clusterCols <- names(sumDat)[grep("cluster",names(sumDat))] # get cluster column names

    # and then aggregate models that have clusters in common
    alwaysSameClusters<-aggregate(sumDat$names,
            by=sumDat[,clusterCols],pasteAlphabetical)
```

That gives you lists of models that are always associated in the same cluster.

I'm not sure what exactly you want do but that should give you the principles to follow, including for a large number of datasets.